# Object inheritance and method parameters/return types - Please check my logic

Tags: object-oriented, uml, inheritance

I'm preparing for a test and doing practice questions, this one in particular I am unsure I did correctly:

We are given a very simple UML diagram to demonstrate inheritance: I hope this is clear, it shows that W inherits from V and so on:

```
                  |-----Y
V <|----- W<|-----|
                  |-----X<|----Z
```

and this code:

```
public X method1(){....}
method2(new Y());
method2(method1());
method2(method3());
```

**The questions and my answers:**

1. **Q:** What types of objects could method1 actually return?

   **A:** X and Z, since the method definition includes X as the return type and since Z is a kind of X is would be OK to return either.
2. **Q:** What could the parameter type of method2 be?

   **A:** Since method2 in the code accepts Y, X and Z (as the return from method1), the parameter type must be either V or W, as Y,X and Z inherit from both of these.
3. **Q:** What could return type of method3 be?

   **A:** Return type of method3 must be V or W as this would be consistent with answer 2.

Comment: You must distinguish between "necessary" and "sufficient" a bit more carefully. The return type of `method3` need not be *identical* to the parameter type of `method2` - the evidence only proves that it's *compatible*.

Comment: First two questions you're good. Method3 could however return X, couldn't it?

Comment: I think the code is confusing. Could you format it for readability and add the curly braces that are missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method3() result can belong to V or W. So, it can be of any type, as any type here belong to V.

Others two are OK

Answer (score -1):

`method3` might have a return type that is anything that could be accepted by `method2`, which means `V`, `W` and every subclass of `W` since all of them could be accepted by `method2`. Given how little we know about `method3` there is really no cause to pretend we know that it's return type must be just `V` or `W`. The less we know, the more possibilities there are.